# Using function with ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My problem is fairly simple. I am working with ng-switch in AngularJS and am trying to get ng-switch-when to take in the variable returned from my beenAdded() function, which is called in the parent ng-switch "on" directive. It does not seem to be accepting the value. Is there a way to use functions with ng-if? Any ideas?

Thanks!

In my HTML:

```
<span ng-switch on="beenAdded(id)">
    <span ng-switch-when="false">
        //do something
    </span>
</span>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.beenAdded = function(var) {
    if (some logic here){
        return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work. Is the missing " in the on expression a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead?

```
<span ng-if="beenAdded(id) == false">
   //do something
</span>
```

And a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/F2tFj/).